# Usar faker para dar de forma aleatoria un id a cada nuevo registro

Tags: php, laravel, php8

estoy creando data con faker en laravel al momento de realizar la migración. Estoy creando communes las cuales pertenecen a un country. Sin embargo al momento de realizar la migración con los seeders (usando el comando php artisan migrate:fresh --seed), me crea correctamente todas las communes y countries, pero a todas las communes les da el mismo id de country.

Estas son las lineas de codigo que utlizo, primero creo 194 countries por factory y luego creo 50 communes, intentando asignarles un country de forma random (en for($country->random()))

```
$country = Country::factory()->count(194)->create();

$commune = Commune::factory()->count(50)->for($country->random())->create();
```

Como podria hacer para que a las communes les de un id de country diferente de forma aleatorea y no el mismo a todas?

De esta forma tengo mi factory de Country:

```
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->country        
        ];
    }
```

Y de esta mi forma mi factory de commune:

```
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->city,
        ];
    }
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: acabo de actualizarlo de como tengo mis factories en el post, gracias!

Comment: gracias @porloscerrosΨ puedo adaptarlo para hacer algo parecido a lo que necesito, pero encontre una forma de agregarle el id de forma aleatoria usando afterMaking en el  comando del seeder, de todas maneras te agradesco mucho tu respuesta y consideración!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver mi problema, encontre la función afterMaking, dentro de la cual, creo una función para asignar un id de un country al azar (usando random)

```
        $country = Country::factory()->count(194)->create();

        $commune = Commune::factory()->count(50)
        ->afterMaking(function (Commune $commune) use ($country) {
            $commune->country_id = $country->random()->id;
        })
        ->create();
```